# How can I upload files to Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, upload

Before Google Docs became Google Drive, I could upload Word documents I wanted to edit, but now I seem unable to do it. Am I missing something, or is there really no way to upload files to Google Drive through the web interface? So far I've had to email the document to myself, open it in Google Drive and save it, which works in a pinch, but is a bit too 90's for my tastes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Upload button is right next to the **Create** button. It looks like a hard disk drive with an up arrow coming out of it.

[image: Upload button]

Comment: In fairness, that icon is quite difficult to see on a smaller screen.   In the size shown here, it's obviously "upload" but this is the first time I've seen it that large.

Comment: @MaryC.fromNZ it's not obvious for me - if I see an icon next to some text on a button, I assume they are the same button like it has been in GUIs for a decade.